# How does the overflow property work with the ul element?

Tags: css, list, drop-down-menu, properties

In [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar) of a drop down menu navigation bar at w3school, when all the `li` elements gets `float: left;`, the `background-color` of `ul` is gone, but adding `overflow: hidden;` brings it back. How does that work?

Comment: Use display:inline; on li elements instead of float:left. That would solve your purpose without the overflow:hidden hack.

Answer (score 1):

The `float: left` removes `li` elements from the flow inside `ul` element. Since `li` are the only children of `ul`. 'ul' does not contain "anything" therefore no background. `overflow: hidden` is a technique similar to "clearfix" to force containment of float children.

Have a read on this link - [Simple Tips on Containing Floats](http://pageaffairs.com/notebook/containing-floats/)